How Does Energy Dissipation Affect Momentum Conservation and Resistance to Flow?
I’m seeking clarification on the relationship between energy dissipation, momentum conservation, and resistance to flow in turbulent fluid dynamics.
Specifically:
How does the dissipation of kinetic energy as heat due to viscous effects influence momentum conservation in a fluid system? Although energy is converted into heat, how does this process impact the overall momentum balance described by Newton's laws and Momentum conservation of lumped models (Reynold Transport Theorem form)?
$\sum \vec{F} = \frac{d}{dt} \iiint_{\text{CV}} ( \vec{V}) \rho \, d\mathcal{V} + \iint_{\text{CS}} (\vec{V}) \rho (\vec{V}_r \cdot \vec{n}) \, dA$
I’m interested in understanding the interplay between these factors and how they affect the analysis and prediction of fluid flow behavior.
Thank you for your insights!

You need to replace the pV dot n in the control surface term with the appropriate term for a viscous newtonian fluid..
